# jQuery listview refresh when JSON data changes

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have some data in my database. I select the data with PHP and MySQL and put it in JSON.
I load the JSON on my other site into my listview. It works. But what I want is when the JSON data changes, my listview should reload automatically.

jQuery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
  var url="url";

    $.getJSON(url,function(json){
      $.each(json.post,function(i,post){
      $("ul:jqmData(role='listview')").append("<li>"+post.naam+"</li>").listview('refresh');
    });
  });
});
```

I hope someone can help me.

Thanks.

Comment: When *does* the JSON data change?

Comment: How your json data changes automatically???

Comment: I think what you want is to use ajax polling. You need to set an interval which checks for new posts (or modifications) and append them to your list. it is not possible for the server to notify the client by itself

Comment: When I change the name in the database the JSON data changes also

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to refresh every 10s and you have no idea if your server has changed the data, you should pull the data every 10s then empty your listview and refresh data :

```
var autorefresh = null;
function autoUpdate(){

  if(autorefresh)
       clearTimeout(autorefresh);

    autorefresh=null;
    $.getJSON(url,function(json){
          var $list = $("ul:jqmData(role='listview')");
          $list.empty();
          $.each(json.post,function(i,post){
              $list.append("<li>"+post.naam+"</li>");
        });
          $list.listview('refresh');

          autorefresh=setTimeout(autoUpdate,10000);
    });
}

$(autoUpdate);
```

You might want to secure the getJson in case there is an error which I didnt do here.